# Падежные формы существительного: Николай или Николаем?

Tags: словоформы

Один знакомый посетовал, что ему очень не нравится, когда на вопрос "Как Вас зовут?" следует ответ с употреблением творительного падежа имени собственного. Ему режут слух фразы типа "Меня зовут Николаем", а импонирует ответ "Меня зовут Николай". Я считаю обе формы равнозначными, но какое-то отличие все же есть.По-моему, именительный падеж препочтительней в книжной речи, а творительный - в устной, разговорной. Искал у Розенталя - не нашел. Может, кто-нибудь из коллег поделится своими соображениями?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮМ.:ЧеРо, 1999](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm)
Существительное и прилагательное в функции именной части составного сказуемого могут стоять как в форме именительного, так и в форме творительного падежа; ср.: И в семье его Савельич был свой человек(Мельников:Печерский). – И у Ивашиных он был своим человеком (Чехов); День был тусклый, теплый (Шукшин):

Обычно в этих случаях именительный падеж сущ. указывает на устойчивый признак предмета, на постоянно присущую ему качественную характеристику, а творительный падеж – на временный признак. Ср. у Пушкина: Германн был сын обрусевшего немца. – Бопре в отечестве своем был парикмахером, потом в Пруссии солдатом. Однако это разграничение не проводится последовательно, например: А Давид... был сначала пастух (В. Панова) (употреблена форма именительного падежа, хотя указывается временный признак); Дом, мимо которого бежала Аночка, был городской школой (Федин) (употреблена форма творительного падежа, хотя имеется в виду постоянный признак);

При глаголе ЗВАТЬ употребляется как именительный, так и творительный падеж, без предпочтений, (зовут как? и зовут кем?каким именем?)например:...Все звали ее Люба (Фадеев); ...Звали его Иваном Ивановичем (Гаршин);

Comment: Во всей этой истории все-таки не очень понятно, что влияет на выбор формыю ибо какое-то внутреннее, но вполне объективное, предпочтение, безусловно, есть. Сведение к постоянному/временному признаку, честно говоря, выглядит весьма натянутым.

Comment: Ну, иностранцам это объясняют так: Если ситуация не ограничена во времени, то предпочтителен именительный падеж, хотя возможен и творительный: Ему приписывали и мудрость, и высокое происхождение, а он сам был простой наемный косец(Л. Леонов).
Он был незаурядный шаман, и этот дар он унаследовал от отца (В. Арсеньев) 
Если ситуация ограничена во времени, например, она имела место в некоторый более ранний момент времени, а затем прекратилась, для именного сказуемого более предпочтителен творительный падеж:
 До того, как сломал ногу, он был жокеем (Тарахно).

Comment: Ничего это не добавляет в понимании. По сути - только путает. Вопрос-то не в том, что такое постоянный или временный признак, а в том, влияет ли реально это как-то на выбор варианта. 

Для себя я никак не могу решить, чем я буду руководствоваться, выбирая ту или иную форму, но точно знаю, что в конкретном случае скажу только так, а не иначе. Во всех Ваших примерах их классиков выбрал бы творительный - и не задумывался. Но если бы имело место противопоставление (как в моем примере с титулярным советником и генеральской дочерью) однозначно именительный. Но это не обобщается...

Comment: Зачем усложнять? В современном русском оба варианта правильны (по Розенталю). Кому какой нравится - тот и выбирают,почему непременно нужны строгие правила? И что-то не вижу Ваших примеров с генеральской дочерью.А титулярный советник как раз подходит - ситуация не ограничена во времени. У Пушкина, кстати,в черновиках то "звалась Татьяна", то "Татьяной".

Answer (score 2):

> > По-моему, именительный падеж предпочтительней в книжной речи, а творительный - в устной, разговорной.

Не думаю. Скорее уж наоборот. Но вернее всего - форма творительного падежа уступает форме именительного.

Но вообще-то тут надо разбираться "от печки". 
Формы типа "он был строитель/строителем", "он стал красный/красным" - и все подобные с разными глаголами - испытывают определенные колебания, по не совсем, правда, понятным, причинам и условиям:

"Итак, она звалась Татьяной"
"Он был титулярный советник"
И кто прав?

Answer (score 2):

Меня зовут... Действительно, а как зовут - Татьяна или Татьяной (как у Пушкина)? Слышишь и так и эдак. По-быстрому  в справочниках по правописанию обоснованный ответ я не нашла , поэтому  ссылаюсь на толковые словари.

Толковом словарь Ушакова - зва́ли кого как (твор. или им. п.). О чьем-н. имени. Меня зовут Иваном. Ленина звали Владимир Ильич. В Ушакова - два падежа: Меня зовут Николай/Николаем.

Ожегов - (кем?) именовать, называть: Его зовут Николаем.

Толковый словарь Кузнецова - (кем?).  Именовать, называть по имени, прозвищу, кличке. Его зовут Иваном Петровичем. Все звали его боцманом.

Наверное, более употребляемая форма тв.п., хотя и. п. встречается довольно-таки часто.

Answer (score 2):

В вопросе "Как тебя зовут?", наверное, предполагается слово "все". Тогда ответ должен быть в тв. пад. Чтобы ответ был в им. пад., надо поинтересоваться: "Как (какое) твоё имя"?  Это чисто интуитивно(а интуиция меня иногда подводит).

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю правильного ответа, но для себя решила, что всё дело в разных значениях глагола "зовут". Одно из значений - "голосом, жестом приглашать приблизиться, подойти или откликнуться"[здесь][1]. Видимо, именно это значение лежит в основе фразы типа МЕНЯ ЗОВУТ НИКОЛАЙ. **Зовут**  в этом значении требует именительного падежа, ср.: *Меня зовут:"Николай!"* Постепенно значение глагола **зовут** в предложениях такого типа перестало ассоциироваться с зовом, с призывом, с обращением. А форма осталась.

[Малый академический словарь](http://dic.academic.ru)   — М.: Институт русского языка Академии наук СССР